# Trying to get Flow redirect working with a Lightning Component that is running a Flow. Any help would be much appreciated

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-components

I think that I am missing something small or then my whole logic is wrong with this.
Here is the Lightning Component, that has been copied from a Salesforce Developer sites.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_cmp.htm

COMPONENT:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,lightning:availableForFlowActions,lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">
  <aura:attribute name="AccountID" type="String" />
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
  <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default slds-theme_backgroundColor-lightblue">
     <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}"/>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
({
    init : function (component) {
        // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
        var flow = component.find("flowData");
        // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow's API Name.
        flow.startFlow("Account_Override");
    },
    handleStatusChange : function (component, event) {
        if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
            var outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
            var outputVar;
            for (var i = 0; i < outputVariables.length; i++) {
                outputVar = outputVariables[i];
                if (outputVar.name === "redirect") {
                    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
                    urlEvent.setParams({
                        "AccountID": outputVar.value,
                        "isredirect": "true"
                    });
                    urlEvent.fire();
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `force:navigateToSObject` is deprecated. You would want to use the lighting navigation service instead.
Here's a demo of how the component would look alike,

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowActions">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="sObject" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="mode" type="String" default="view" />
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService" />
</aura:component>
```

------------JS-----------------------

```
({
  invoke: function (component, event, helper) {
    var navService = component.find("navService");
    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    var objectName = component.get("v.sObject");
    var mode = component.get("v.mode").toLowerCase();
    // Open the Record page in View mode first so that it persists after the Edit Modal closes
    var pageReference = {
      type: "standard__recordPage",
      attributes: {
        recordId: recordId,
        objectApiName: objectName,
        actionName: "view"
      }
    };
    navService.navigate(pageReference);

    if (mode == "edit") {
      var pageReference = {
        type: "standard__recordPage",
        attributes: {
          recordId: recordId,
          objectApiName: objectName,
          actionName: mode
        }
      };
      navService.navigate(pageReference);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the demo, I will try it out. Thank you also pointing out that force:navigateToSObject is deprecated, should've noticed that. Also apologies for the wrong indentation with the question.